# Replace two strings with each other

Tags: replace, query-replace

I would like to change all occurrences of a string (say string1) with another string (say string2) and vice-versa. To be precise I have a long document and these strings occur many times. What I currently do, is to replace string1-->string3, then string2-->string1 and finally string3-->string2.

I am wondering if there is already a function in emacs which does this.  Other solutions are welcomed.

**Edit**: This is actually a duplicate of the question linked in the comment. But the problem is that the accepted answer of that question does not always work (see the comment below). I think it is better to wait until the author of that accepted answer corrects his/her answer or some other solution comes out. Secondly before posting my question, I googled the question and that question did not show up. I think having two duplicate questions is sometimes useful since they use different wording and if a user find the duplicate one, he/she can find the right one.

**Edit 2:** The accepted answer of [Search/replace-like feature for swapping text](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27135/search-replace-like-feature-for-swapping-text) seems to be fine now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search/replace-like feature for swapping text](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27135/search-replace-like-feature-for-swapping-text)

Comment: @T.Verron I tried to use the accepted answer of your link to replace "This" with "that" in the scratch buffer but it does not work.

Comment: Maybe I accepted too fast. Commenting the last two arguments out (`backwards` and `region-noncontiguous-p`) in the call of `perform-replace` makes it work here (emacs 24.3). I'll test it on emacs 25 when I get an occasion before editing the other answer.

Comment: @T.Verron by contrast, the other solution suggesting to use the package plur. It seems to work in this situation without problem.

Comment: I have changed the accepted answer in the other question. Regarding google, yes, I too had trouble finding keywords to convey what I was trying to do. And yes, duplicates are good! https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the interactive case query-replace-regexp (C-M-%) can do this, using the relatively unknown \, for the replacement.

```
C-M-% \(string1\)\|\(string2\)
\,(if (equal \& "string1") "string2" "string1")
```

If the replacement text contains \, followed by a lisp expression, it uses the value of that expression as the replacement. In this case the expression is an "if" which takes a condition and the return value for the true and false cases.

In the comments it is suggested to use

> \,(if \1 "string2" "string1")

This works because \1 will be "string1" if the pattern matches string1, and will be nil otherwise. Lisp takes any non-nil value as true. Whilst this works and is shorter, I think my answer is more useful. I think the code is more readable to someone whose lisp knowledge is limited. It has a second advantage as it still works if the "from" pattern is given as

```
\(string1\|string2\)
```

or even

```
string1\|string2
```

Comment: Some comment in the duplicate candidate suggested the simpler syntax `\,(if \1 "string2" "string1")`, using the regexp `\(string1\)\|string2`.

Comment: See the last two paragraphs of [`(emacs) Regexp Replace`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html).

Answer (score -2):

Well, maybe with a macro this would be easy:

<kbd>F3</kbd><kbd>C-s</kbd>`a`<kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>C-b</kbd><kbd>M-t</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>. Using this macro on your question yells this result:

> I would like to change all occurrences of string a (say string1) with
>   another string (say string2) and vice-versa. To be precise I have long
>   a document and these strings occur many times. What I currently do, is
>   to replace string1-->string3, then string2-->string1 and finally
>   string3-->string2.
>
> I am wondering if there is already function a in emacs which does
>   this. Other solutions are welcomed.

I'm transposing positions between whatever word is after an `a` and that word. You can later edit such macro to transpose other words as well without needing to redefine the entire macro, you can edit the macro with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>.

Comment: I don't think the question is related to transposing words.

Comment: @T.Verron It is, but he wants a more automatized approach, it seems.

Comment: What your macro does is exchanging (transposing) each "a" with the next word. "a string" > "string a" etc. What he wants to do is e.g. replace each "a" with "the" and each "the" with "a".